# Status of the "anabelian dream" ($\mathrm{dim} \leq 1$)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, anabelian-geometry

The anabelian conjectures for small dimensions have been known for quite some time. In full generality the results are:

- Dimension 0. Finitely generated fields are anabelian (Pop)
- Dimension 1. Hyperbolic curves over number fields are anabelian (Mochizuki)

Most of the focus on anabelian geometry these days seems to be on the section conjecture, the birational program...

But the main purpose of Grothendieck's program was to classify all anabelian varieties in all dimensions over all fields.

> My question is, is the opposite direction of Pop's
>   and Mochizuki's results known?

The absence of discussion of this point on the relevant literature makes we wonder if perhaps the converse result is obvious.

It is easy to find some examples. For example, finite fields are completely non-anabelian. Archimedean local fields too, by Artin-Schreier. But alredy for non-archimedean local fields, it is not clear to me that they *can't* be anabelian, and the structure of their absolute  Galois groups is quite well known.

Edit. (**Clarification**) Consider for example the full subcategory of finitely generated fields and field isomorphisms. The "absolute Galois gruop functor" to the category of profinite groups  and outer isomorphisms is fully faithful. The kind of problem I have in mind is

> Is this the maximal full subcategory of the category of field for
>   which this is true? Are there other interesting subcategories with the same property?

Comment: An "anabelian" variety is a variety which is determined up to isomorphism by its étale fundamental group?

Comment: @Qfwfq Exactly.

Comment: Could you please clarify further what you mean?  For a hyperbolic curve $C$, there are plenty of other algebraic varieties that have the same fundamental group as $C$, e.g., $\mathbb{P}^1\times C$.  Do you want to characterize morphisms to $C$ in terms of homomorphisms to the etale fundamental group of $C$?  Certainly $\mathbb{P}^1\times C$ has no such characterization.

Comment: You can improve to sub p-aic fields instead of number fields. Furthermore if you accept filtration as additional information, local fields will satisfy Neukirch-Uchida.

Comment: I thought that there was no concrete definition of "anabelian varieties" in higher dimensions as the etale fundamental group is less powerful of an invariant. Perhaps a more natural thing to ask is that the etale homotopy type is a $K(\pi , 1)$? That can be phrased purely in terms of galois cohomology and etale cohomology. I should also add there is a preprint by Schmidt and Stix obtaining some partial results in higher dimensions by using the etale homotopy type point of view.

Comment: @JoeBerner That's an interesting condition but perhaps you shouldn't use the word "anabelian" for it as then all abelian varieties would be anabelian.

Comment: I forgot to add a "not abelian" condition on $\pi_1$! Of course, Achinger's recent results in characteristic $p$ make me question if this is the right condition for non-proper varieties.